# Why does Text.Show.Functions only return <function>?

Tags: haskell, reflection

The standard package to show functions only returns a constant string:

```
λ> :m +Text.Show.Functions 
λ> show (+1)
"<function>"
```

GHCi's `:type` command is much more useful:

```
λ> :t (+1)
(+1) :: Num a => a -> a
```

Is it impossible to get such a level of detail at runtime? Does the compilation process leave any kind of information at all about functions, except for them being functions?

Comment: [The wiki has some information](https://wiki.haskell.org/Show_instance_for_functions) on this subject.

Comment: @gspr Thanks. I figured it was a reason like that. But it still does not explain whether it could theoretically output anything more than `<function>`, such as the type signature, or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not exactly the same level of details, but you can use `typeOf` from [Data.Typeable](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.1.0/docs/Data-Typeable.html#v:typeOf):

```
Prelude> import Data.Typeable
Prelude Data.Typeable> typeOf (+1)
Integer -> Integer
```

Comment: I downvoted. This doesn't appear to address the question as asked, which is about motivation rather than alternatives.

Comment: @DanielWagner Yes, motivation for the limited output of show was my primary question. Data.Typeable is interesting, but it seems to lack builtin or automatic instances for most functions, for example `(+1)` works, but `const (+1)` fails miserably

Comment: @Tobia `Typeable` is derived for most types.  The problem you present is one of polymorphism - const introduces a free type variable that needs to be monomorphic for `typeOf`.  Try `typeOf (const (+1) :: String -> Int -> Int)`